# Вычислить количество цифр целого неотрицательного числа n

Tags: c#

Задача максимально простая, но на сайте проходит только 6/8 проверок. С другим вариантом кода (без строки) все работает на 8/8. Что конкретно не так?
**Входные данные:**
*Одно целое неотрицательное число n (0 ≤ n ≤ 2 ∙10^9).*
 **Вычислить количество цифр целого неотрицательного числа n**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{                                  
     Console.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine().Length); 
     Console.ReadKey(); 
}
```

---

Рабочий вариант:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    long x =Convert.ToInt64(Console.ReadLine()); int count = 0;
    do
    {
        x /= 10;
        count++;
    } while (x > 0);
    Console.WriteLine(count);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: длина для строки "2∙0^9" посчитается как 5. А второй вариант это какой? Приложите код второго варианта к вопросу.

Comment: "С другим вариантом кода (без строки)" - ??

Comment: Рабочий вариант тоже нерабочий, потому что 0. А то бы ответы - в ответы, а не в вопрос.

Comment: @Qwertiy♦ ? Для 0 тоже все работает, выводит 1. И как я уже упомянул - рабочий вариант проверен проверяющим сайтом

Comment: А, точно, там же do while, а не просто while. Тогда это в ответы, а из вопроса удалить.

Comment: В первом варианте, строку можно сконвертировать в Int64, а потом обратно в строку, чтобы решить проблему чисел типа 2e10